# GLchar is undefined

Tags: c++

I tried to install glew and glfw. Everything was fine with glfw, but after installing glew, the error "GLchar" is undefined appeared

```
#include <glfw3.h>
#include <glew.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "glew is not ok" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

either I searched badly or it's not on the internet, but I didn't find it on the internet.

Comment: Please show the entire error message.

Answer (score 0):

Read errors in order. The first error I get is:

```
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:85:2: error: #error gl.h included before glew.h
   85 | #error gl.h included before glew.h
      |  ^~~~~
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:97:2: error: #error glext.h included before glew.h
   97 | #error glext.h included before glew.h
      |  ^~~~~
```

So just swap the first two lines to include `glew.h` first. When I do this, your source code compiles.

Comment: at first, this error did not occur after reading the answer, it appeared

Comment: @sigma If this was the solution to your answer, could you mark that solution as accepted?

Answer (score -1):

Try swapping `#include <glfw3.h>` and `#include <glew.h>`.

Also, I recommend using `using namespace std;` to remove the `std::` before "cout" and "endl".

Comment: Please read: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10871073)